# How to decode BASE64 in Standard SQL?

Tags: sql, base64, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to unhash a column of base64 values into decoded strings with Standard SQL in BigQuery and not having any luck so far.

I found there's a function called `FROM_BASE64()` but -

A. The documentation makes it appear as though it converts BASE64 into BYTES, which means I'd need an additional conversion.

B. `FROM_BASE64()` is not even working - the query runs, but the results are always the exact same encoded string that I inputted.

```
SELECT FROM_BASE64('aGVsbG8tc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw==')
```

returns

```
"aGVsbG8tc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw=="
```

What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Base64 is a *byte* level encoding algorithm, so that is why the output of `FROM_BASE64()` is a `BYTES`.

As long as you don't need to display the decoded bytes, you can work with them in your queries as needed. But raw bytes might not be *displayable* as-is in BigQuery, so it might chose to display them in BASE64 instead. Thus, your example would simply decode the string literal to bytes and then re-encoding the result back to Base64, which would explain why you see your input string as the output.

You can cast a `BYTES` to a `STRING`, but that only works if the raw bytes represent a valid UTF-8 encoded string.
Or, you can use `SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING()` to decode a `BYTES` to a `STRING` replacing any non-valid UTF-8 bytes with Unicode codepoint U+FFFD.

Alternatively, you can use `FORMAT()` to display each byte in a `BYTES` in hex `\x##` format.

Comment: Wow! That handles that:

`SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(FROM_BASE64('aGVsbG8tc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw=='))`
=
`hello-stackoverflow`